# download using Alamofire failed with app termination

Tags: swift, alamofire, appdelegate, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, urlsession

i want to write a downloader app i wrote pretty much of it but i have a serious problem my request simply cancels when the user terminates the app and when i run the app again i must download it from the beginning and i don't know how to store resume data just before app termination any idea? for example, how can download the file and store it continuously as it downloads so when anything happens i could  my downloaded data something like making an empty file and fill it with data as the request goes on if i solve this problem my app will become complete please help me if you can

```
func StartDownload () {


let fileUrl = self.getSaveFileUrl(fileName: Data[0] as String)
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
    return (fileUrl, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}


downloadRequest = Alamofire.download(Data[0] as String , to:destination)



    .downloadProgress { (progress) in

        self.progressCircle.progress = progress.fractionCompleted

    }


    .response { defaultDownloadResponse in
        self.Timeer?.invalidate()
        if let error = defaultDownloadResponse.error {
            print("someThing went wrong \(error)")
            if let resumeDataa = defaultDownloadResponse.resumeData {
                let Resume = CachableData(urll: self.Data[0].lastPathComponent as String, Resume: resumeDataa)
                self.cacher.persist(item: Resume) { url, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Text failed to persist: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Text persisted in \(url?.absoluteString ?? "fuck")")
                        return
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else {

        if self.Data.count >= 2 {
            self.Data.removeFirst()
            self.startButton.isHidden = false
            self.pauseButton.isHidden = true
            self.resumeButton.isHidden = true

        }
        else if self.Data.isEmpty == true {
            return
        }
        else {
            self.sendNotif(state: true)
            self.Data.removeLast()
            self.startButton.isHidden = true
            self.pauseButton.isHidden = true
            self.resumeButton.isHidden = true
        }
        if !self.Data.isEmpty {
            self.StartDownload()
        }

        self.progressCircle.progress = 0
        self.progressLabel.text = "0%"
        self.stateLabel.text = "Downloaded"
        self.downloadTableView.reloadData()
        self.SaveData()

}
}
```

}

Comment: Did you write it with code? Where is the code?

Comment: Yes i wrote start download code and its okay i can resume download when i press resume or when i disconnect from internet but i want to resume when app suddenly terminated by user i write my function below see it

Comment: Put the code in the question

Comment: I did this is my main function

Comment: `print("Text persisted in \(url?.absoluteString ?? "fuck")")` I'm not sure that's the most useful for your own diagnostics 

Comment: Im really confused with this issue so i did things like this can you help me? How should i store resumedata before app terminatiom

Answer (score 0):

You can use life cycle of the app as you know there are function for each of them. When your up terminate you can save your data before you app terminates.

Comment: but life cycles are in the app delegate class how can send resume data to appdelegate class or how can i for example tell alamofire to save resume data while request is running